# How can I create a scrollable list of sentences in a subplot of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am currently working on a project where I mine details from a social media service on a companies intranet and do some sentiment analysis.  I am putting together a proof of concept application in python with tkinter and matplotlib and the request was made to be able to click on outliers and read the post (Why I didn't think of that to begin with is beyond me).

So, in a nutshell, I have a tkinter window with 4 subplots and a space for a 5th.  I would like to click on a point in the scatter plot from subplot 1 and have it display the text, or list of texts (if there are stacked points) in subplot 5.  I have most of it worked out where I now can print a list in the terminal of the posts but for the life of me cannot figure out how to get that text into a nice table format in the proper subplot.  I have been playing around with plt.table() but I'm struggling.  I would like a nicely formatted list of posts of varying sizes for the user to scroll through when they click on the scatter point(s).  Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the code I am working with.

```
def onpick3(event):
    global ind
    ind = event.ind
    xd = event.mouseevent.xdata
    yd = event.mouseevent.ydata

a.scatter(xList, yList, picker=True) #plot
a.axis([-1,1,0,1])
f.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)

try:
    for data_points in ind:
        df_score_lookup = dfs[(dfs['avg_pol']==xList[data_points]) & (dfs['avg_sub']==yList[data_points])]
        score_lookup_list = df_score_lookup['id'].tolist()
        df_content_lookup = dfd[dfd['id'].isin(score_lookup_list)]
        txt_table_content = df_content_lookup['content'].tolist()
        #colLables = ['Comments']
        #comment = ''
        a5.table(loc='top', cellText=comment)#, loc='top')#colLabels=colLables)#, loc='center')
        #x=0
        #for comment in txt_table_content:
        #    print comment
        #    a5.table.add_cell(x,0,text=str(comment))
        #    x=x+1
except: pass
```

Comment: Since you seem to be using a GUI toolkit anyway, it might be easier to use a text widget rather than a subplot to show the text.

Comment: I agree with @kazemakase. Why you didn't think of that to begin with is beyond me. Scrolling lists of text are not amongst matplotlib's strengths.

Comment: So my current layout has 2x2 subplots above a subplot that spans the window left to right. I then have a slider below that. How would i put a tkinter widget into the lower right subplot area above the subplot that spans the page?